# Load LUBM University data to Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, rdf, graph-databases, lubm

I am trying to upload LUBM data set to Neo4j server. I went through neo4j tutorial and there is something called 'batch import'. To use that I should have two CSV files.

1. Nodes.CSV
2. Relations.CSV

The problem is in University data set there are nodes from multiple types(University, Department, Professor). So I think I cannot do it using single nodes.CSV file. I think someone should have done this before. Great if someone can help me to load LUBM data.

LUBM - Lehigh University Benchmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need several `.csv` file per type/label and make sure to conform the following specification:

CSV file format

> The CSV file to use with LOAD CSV must have the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - the character encoding is UTF-8;
> - the end line termination is system dependent, e.g., it is \n on unix or \r\n on windows;
> - the default field terminator is ,;
> - the field terminator character can be change by using the option FIELDTERMINATOR available in the LOAD CSV command;
> - quoted strings are allowed in the CSV file and the quotes are dropped when reading the data;
> - the character for string quotation is double quote ";
> - the escape character is .

[neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html#csv-file-format)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can share a link to the original dataset. In general for batch import there is comprehensive documentation (including examples) available:

- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html
- http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl
- http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets